# R Code-Random Forest Regression-Variable Importance Analysis- Significance Testing

Tags: r, random-forest

Good day,

I am performing a Variable Importance Analysis using the Randomforest package. The model runs fine and I get the output I desire. However, I want to test the statistical significance of the estimates of variable importance derived from the data. Can anyone explain how this can be performed in R?

Thank you! 
JAM

Comment: This is not done, the variable importances as they are are based on permutations and scaled on a common scale for all the variables. There is no mean or SD to perform inference.

Comment: Thank you for this information. Appreciate it!